# How do I prove that if a linear system has infinite solutions then the homogeneous also has infinite solutions ( Is that true ? )

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I would like to know if it is true that if an inhomogeneous system has infinite solutions then the homogeneous also has infinite solutions. Here I some of my guesses about it?

To have infinite solutions means that during the process of scaling process ( Not sure if that is the word. ) one line will become full of zeros, I see that if it happens to the inhomogeneous then it has to happen with the homogeneous, what i fail to understand is how i can prove that a little bit more rigorously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that subtracting two solutions to the inhomogeneous problem produces a solution to the homogeneous problem.  In terms of matrices: if $Ax = b$ and $Ay = b$, then $A(x - y) = 0$.

Comment: I see, loved the hint. Thank you very much.